# count check boxes in asp.net table usin java script and disable others

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am very much new to asp and java:
i have designed a page with a table and some checkboxes inside that table i want to set a condition using script to alert user not to check more than four checkboxes. Or if user checks four checkboxes the other remaining checkboxes available in this table must get disabled and if the user unchecks any of the selected checkboxes all the disabled shall get enabled back for new selection. There are some check boxes which belong to same group (cell) which if user clicks one of them the other selected checkboxes in that group(cell) must get unchecked just like toggle in nutshell only one checkbiox must get selected in that cell.I have done that in java but dont know how to have check on the checkboxes more than four. 
(P.S) In (group I)  of the table checkbox GE is cheked and disabled this check box is mandatory among four checkbox it should be always checked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChkValidate() {
        var counter = 0;


        var panel = document.getElementById ("panel1")
        for (i = 0; i < panel.children.length; i++) {
            if (panel.children[i].type == 'checkbox')
            {
                if (panel.children[i].checked == true) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter > 4)

            {
                alert('You have reached to maximum selection');
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

     function aspcheckED0() {
         document.getElementById("PS0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPS0() {
         document.getElementById("ED0").checked = false;

     }

    function aspcheckEL0() {
        document.getElementById("HS0").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("MA0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckHS0() {
         document.getElementById("EL0").checked = false;
         document.getElementById("MA0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckMA0() {
         document.getElementById("EL0").checked = false;
         document.getElementById("HS0").checked = false;
     }

     function aspcheckUR0() {
         document.getElementById("PJ0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPJ0() {
         document.getElementById("UR0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckAR0() {
         document.getElementById("PR0").checked = false;
     }
     function aspcheckPR0() {
         document.getElementById("AR0").checked = false;
     }

    </script>



        <table id="artstable" align="center" class="auto-style53" style="border: thin dotted #6666FF; font-family: Verdana;
        border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #E6E6E6;">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style188" colspan="10"><strong>Enter Your Admission Details</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong> Select Your Course:</strong></td>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="54px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700;" Width="385px">
                        <asp:ListItem>BA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSC</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSCN</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BCOM</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><strong>B.A</strong></td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style113" colspan="0">Group&nbsp; 1</td>
                <td class="auto-style162">Group&nbsp; 2</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style114">Group 3</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style95">Group 4</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style150">Group 5</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style174">Group 6</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style160">Group 7</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style136">Group 8</td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style116">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><span class="auto-style43">Select Any four </span>
                    <br class="auto-style43" />
                    <span class="auto-style43">subjects ,Max one from<br /> each group</span></td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style117">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ge" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="GE"   onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style163" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PS" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="PS"  onclick="aspcheckPS();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ED" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="ED"  onclick="aspcheckED();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style118">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ec" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="EC"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style96">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="kr" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"   Text="KR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style151" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="MA" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="MA"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="EL" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="EL"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="HS" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="HS"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"/>
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style175" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="UR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="UR"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PJ" runat="server"  BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="PJ" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style161" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="AR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="AR"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <br class="auto-style139" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="PR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="auto-style137">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="fe" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF"  Text="FE"  onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate();" SkinID="ch"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier and cleaner in jQuery. But if you don't have that option, then do like this:
**EDIT :** Added alert for less than four selections.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChkValidate(elem) {

        ValidateGroup(elem);
        var valid = Validate();
        EnableCheckBoxes(valid);
    };

    function ValidateGroup(elem) {
        if (elem.type == 'checkbox' && elem.checked) {
            var parenttd = elem.parentNode.parentNode;

            var controls = parenttd.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                if (controls[i].type == 'checkbox') controls[i].checked = false;
            }
            elem.checked = true;
        }
    };

    function EnableCheckBoxes(valid) {            
    var tbl = document.getElementById("artstable")
    var controls = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input")

        for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
            if (controls[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                if (!controls[i].checked) controls[i].disabled = !valid;
            }
        }

    };

    function Validate() {
        var valid = true;
        var counter = 0;            
        var tbl = document.getElementById("artstable")
        var controls = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input")

        for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
            if (controls[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                if (controls[i].checked) counter++;
            }
        }

        valid = counter < 4;
        return valid;
    };

    function ValidateSubmission() {
        if (Validate()) {
        alert('Please select four subjects');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
</script>
```

**ASPX MARKUP:**

```
<table id="artstable" align="center" class="auto-style53" style="border: thin dotted #6666FF; font-family: Verdana; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #E6E6E6;">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style188" colspan="10"><strong>Enter Your Admission Details</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong> Select Your Course:</strong></td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style42" colspan="5">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="54px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700;" Width="385px">
                <asp:ListItem>BA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>BSC</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>BSCN</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>BCOM</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><strong>B.A</strong></td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style113" colspan="0">Group&nbsp; 1</td>
        <td class="auto-style162">Group&nbsp; 2</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style114">Group 3</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style95">Group 4</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style150">Group 5</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style174">Group 6</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style160">Group 7</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style136">Group 8</td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style116">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style140" style="border: thin dotted #0000FF"><span class="auto-style43">Select Any four </span>
            <br class="auto-style43" />
            <span class="auto-style43">subjects ,Max one from<br />
                each group</span></td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style117">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ge" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="GE" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style163" rowspan="1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PS" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="PS" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ED" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="ED" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style118">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ec" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="EC" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style96">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="kr" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="KR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style151" rowspan="1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="MA" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="MA" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="EL" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="EL" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="HS" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="HS" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style175" rowspan="1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="UR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="UR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PJ" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="PJ" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style161" rowspan="1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="AR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="AR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <br class="auto-style139" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PR" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="PR" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="auto-style137">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="fe" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFFFF" Text="FE" onclick="javascript:return ChkValidate(this);" SkinID="ch" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick=" return ValidateSubmission();" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

I have tested the code in FF, but should work in other browsers.

Comment: this code worked fine both in i.e and ff thanx for ur timely help brother but there remains an issue when i check the first check box the other check boxes of some different table which are in the same page gets enabled also. By default they remain disabled untill and unless i will not select radio  button other than arts. How to make them disabled on the selection of check boxes in arts table only.

Comment: in hort i just need this java script only for arts table and not for other tables which are in this page

Comment: @arshad - Edited my answer to do operation on checkboexs inside the "artstable" table only.

Comment: @afzalulh- Dear Bro, You are great you have eased my problems in minutes .thanx for your help. I forgot to tell you one more thing. If user selects less than four on btn submit or some where else event it should give him the alert to select four subjects. Because there is a mandatory for the user to select not less than four subjects.  Thanx for help in advance

Comment: I have another javascript function. Also added a submit button at the end of the markup.

Comment: Dear , i am calculating % of two text boxes in the third one. But it all happens on post back and returns value using v.b net.But this is so irritating when it is postbacking on a slow connection. Can we check %age of these text boxes in java too if yes plz reply.....

Comment: Yes, you can. It could be like this: `   var x = document.getElementById('TextBox1');    var y = document.getElementById('TextBox2');    var z = document.getElementById('TextBox3');    z.value = x.value / y.value * 100;`.

Comment: do i need to write it in between <script type="text/javascript"> tags and if yes then how to make it possible on the blur  event of marksobt textbox.  i have three textboxes 1. maxmarks 2. marksobt and percentgae box with id percentage

Comment: Can you email me the markup? As this is not related to this question, better not to continue here.

Comment: as you wish i will mail it to u and one more thing again when you added the function validate submission , once again it should be only for artstable and not for other table because in other courses there are some different subjects so plz make it limited for arts table

Comment: @afzalulh-as you wish i will mail it to u and one more thing again when you added the function validate submission , once again it should be only for artstable and not for other table because in other courses there are some different subjects so plz make it limited for arts table